# Bitbucket gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket, ubuntu-16.04, gnutls

I am having an issue on newly created Ubuntu 16.04 OS with bitbucket.
When I am cloning repo from [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/amepani/my-demos) repository I am getting below error

> Cloning into 'my-demos'... fatal: unable to access
>   'https://amepani@bitbucket.org/amepani/my-demos.git/':
>   gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.

I have gone through [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers/187199#187199) but not able to resolve an issue.
I have updated JDK version and also installed the latest version of git but getting the same error.

Let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi I have faces this issue due to firewall in which bitbucket.org and other sites blocked and observed this issue when user face slow internet connection. 
First, Make sure bitbucket.org accessible

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am facing slow internet connection issue.

Comment: If bitbucket is restricted by VPN and firewall in your organization then there is more chance to see the above error.

Comment: It was the slow internet connection problem for me. It started working own it's own once the internet speed got little better.

Answer (score 4):

Bitbucket uses TLS.

If you are running behind a proxy, try to set your https_proxy.

```
export https_proxy="http://username:password@yourproxy.com:yourproxyport/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that a shell script written by [Paul Backer](https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker) resolved this issue for me. The script recompiles git to use openssl instead of gnutls and after that was done I was able to push to Bitbucket again.

The script is available in his repository https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/git-openssl-shellscript. Read the README for the whole story but it worked for me so thank you Paul.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lower your MTU.

`ifconfig <Interface_name> mtu <mtu_size> up`

In my case, 1400 worked well.

`ifconfig ens3 mtu 1400 up`

My environment is Ubuntu 20.04.